# Check if string contains a number c#

Tags: c#, string, substring, contains

I know that there is lots of questions like this out there.
But I really couldn't find anything that solved my problem.

I want to check if the string contains the specific input number. See the following example:

```
public Boolean checkString()
{
    string input = "2.5.8.12.30";
    string intToFind = "3";

    if (input.contains(intToFind))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This returns true but I want it to return false since the intToFind string is 3 and not 30. So it is the contains() that is the problem.

How do I make it search for 3 only?

Comment: Is the string always delimited by periods?  If not, what other possible formats are there?

Comment: It is always delimited by periods.

Comment: I can see 2 people who downvoted this question. I'm always curious when I get downvoted so if you could leave a comment that would be nice!
I just want to improve and it seems like I've made a mistake or that this question could have a duplicate.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use `String.Split` + `Contains`:

```
bool contains3 = input.Split('.').Contains("3");
```

Comment: This will still return true

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: no, it won't.

Comment: @sm.abdullah: no, it won't. It is `Enumerable.Contains` not `String.Contains`. It'll check if the complete string is contained, not part of it.

Comment: @TimSchmelter ah..Right : )

Comment: This was really nice, I made same mistake thinking that it will use String.Contains. Thanks for the knowledge :)

Comment: Thanks!
I was just about to say that this didn't work but then I realized that I was using " instead of '.
+ 1 and accepted!

Answer (score 7):

```
bool anyThree = input.Split('.').Any(str => str == "3");
```

Comment: That's what `Contains` method is for. This will work, but not straight forward.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel - Your'e the guy that got confused with 'Contains' above and your saying that this isn't straight forward? Common..I agree that I would have probally used the contains solution in my code but stackoverflow isn't a "one answer" site..This is also a good option.

Comment: Confused yes. Does that matters for you? I didn't say this is a not a good option either. I just said, straight forward way to use  `Contains`. No more no less.

Answer (score 2):

You may split your input using `String.Split('.')` into an array. Now use `Array.contains` to check if the element is within the array

```
bool contained = input.Split('.').Contains("3");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] words = input.Split('.');
if (words.contains("3")){do something...}
```

Comment: That should be `words.Contains("3")`.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use Regex which might be a little overkill.

```
string str = "2.5.8.12.30";
string strToFind = "3";
bool contains = Regex.Match(str, string.Format(@"\W{0}\W",strToFind)).Success;
```